# Get filesize of file selected xp:fileUpload in CSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages

I would like to check the size of the file selected in an xp:fileupload control in CSJS so I can prevent it being submitted (and possible fail due to limitations set on a server)

Is this possible?

I find this specification but I am not sure how to use it: https://www.openntf.org/xspext/xpages%20extension%20library%20documentation.nsf/xpages-doc/xp_fileUpload.html#prop_size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing the xp control can do unless some sort of JS client side  functionality has been developed having that in mind.

Of course, the JSF framework can check on the file size only when it's too late, read when it's already been uploaded to the server in its entirety. However I don't discard this possibility since it can still be useful in a fallback scenario.

On the client side of things your option is to use `FileReader` ([compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader)). You can define a function along these lines:

```
function checkFileSize(inputFile) {
    if (!FileReader) return;

    var file = inputFile.files[0];

    if (file && file.size > Number(inputFile.dataset.limit)) {
        inputFile.value = '';
        alert(inputFile.dataset.error);
    }
}
```

The fileUpload (the example is set to work with the onchange, and a limit of 1 MB):

```
<xp:fileUpload id="uploadFile" onchange="checkFileSize(event.target)">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="data-limit" value="1000000" />
        <xp:attr name="data-error" value="The file exceeds 1MB" />
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

Comment: I can live with this approach :-) Thanks for the code. Have been looking at this post too http://xpagexplorer.org/dragdrop-file-upload/

Answer (score 2):

If the browser [supports the FileReader API](https://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader) then you can do the following to get a handle of the file size (assuming that `fileuploadId` is the id of the `xp:fileUpload` control):

```
if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
    // get the file size from the file input field
    if (dojo.byId(fileuploadId) && dojo.byId(fileuploadId).files) {
        var fsize = dojo.byId(fileuploadId).files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's well supported in most current browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader  Have used the filereader api before to do this exact thing.  A solid solution.